# What does the GCC '-g' option do?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb

What is the use of the GCC -g option?

I tried `gcc --help`, but an answer wasn't found.

This is something related to debugging purposes.

Comment: What's actually unclear from the currently available documentation for you?

Comment: Don't expect the `--help` option shows all information. When you need full documentation, please find the documentation. In Linux or Unix, `man gcc` is a good start point. Or, just search it on web. Be aware that if you just put `-g` in google, it will exclude any result of `g`(- means exclusion in google). You have to use keywords such as `gcc "-g"`.

Comment: Thanks @xylosper. I tried -g only. Didn't knew about exclusion in google thing. :)

Comment: The GCC documentation is ***not*** at all easy to navigate (incl. using search engines). Here is [a direct link to `-g`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g).

Comment: If people are finding the answer helpful. Why isn't asking the question helpful? StackOverflow community?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *"I tried `gcc --help` but no answer was found."*

Well, `gcc --help` just provides a very broad overview of the available options and command  line syntax. This [**options summary documentation**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary) might be a better starting point.

As [from the **GCC documentation**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g) it says

> -g
> Produce debugging information in the operating system's native format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF 2). GDB can work with this debugging information.
> On most systems that use stabs format, -g enables use of extra debugging information that only GDB can use; this extra information makes debugging work better in GDB but probably makes other debuggers crash or refuse to read the program. If you want to control for certain whether to generate the extra information, use -gstabs+, -gstabs, -gxcoff+, -gxcoff, or -gvms (see below).

> GCC allows you to use -g with -O. The shortcuts taken by optimized code may occasionally produce surprising results: some variables you declared may not exist at all; flow of control may briefly move where you did not expect it; some statements may not be executed because they compute constant results or their values are already at hand; some statements may execute in different places because they have been moved out of loops.

> Nevertheless it proves possible to debug optimized output. This makes it reasonable to use the optimizer for programs that might have bugs.

> The following options are useful when GCC is generated with the capability for more than one debugging format.